# How to add an URL of jenkins results into testlink as execution result

Tags: jenkins

If I add results manually in testlink I have custom fields to add the start, stop times, url and the hostname as additional information in testlink.  The fields/results are then visible afterwards.

If I'm using Jenkins to run automatic test cases and showing the results in testlink using the testlink plugin, the JUnit xml result is added as attachment but I would like to see also some other custom fields, like the url html file, start and stop times etc.

In Jenkins I am using a script to run a test case and generate a report.

How can I automatically complete the additional information in testlink as execution result?